# Error when setting fields and putting data in a database (H2) from the website using Thymeleaf and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, h2

Apologies in advance for any mistakes when making this post as this is my first time.
I am building (for the first time ground up) an financial tracking website using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot for a personal project. However, I have been stuck on this specific issue for some time and I'm not really sure what to do.

What I wanted to do is create a form where the user of the website could input details of the expense that there are trying to track, with saving this input in my database (I am using H2 until website is done), this includes name, cost and type. I wanted to display the types in select/option HTML tag, however I keep getting multiple errors for this, the recent one is `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'entryDTO' available as request attribute`.

Please see code below

Home.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:Name="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/Home.css}" />
    <link href="/css/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<header style="text-align: center">
    <h1>Welcome <span th:text="${name}"></span></h1> <h1>Finance Tracker</h1>


</header>

<div>
    <form th:action="@{/add-userEntry}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <label for="description">Description:</label>
                <input type="text" id="description"  th:field="*{name}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <label for="amount" >Amount:</label>
                <input type="number" id="amount" min="0" step="0.01" required  th:field="*{entryDTO.cost}" />
                </td>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                <label for="type"> Type:</label>
                    <select id="type" th:field="*{type}">
                        <option th:each="category : ${entry.type}"
                                th:value="${category}"
                                th:text="${category}">
                    </select>

            <!--    Need to add an option for User income -->
                <br>
                </tr>
                <button type="submit" id="/add-userEntry" th:action="@{add-userEntry}">Add</button>

        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<h2>Transactions</h2>

<form action="/expense-list" th:action="@{/expense-list}" th:object="${expenseListModel}" method="GET" >

    <input type="text" method="POST" name="search-name"th:object="${expenseSearchModel}">
    <button type="submit" id="search-name">Search</button>

    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tr th:each="expense: ${expenseListModel}">
            <td th:text="${expense.getExpenseName}">Name:</td>
            <td th:text="${expense.getExpenseCost}">Cost: </td>
            <td th:text="${expense.getExpenseDate}">Date:</td>
            <td th:text="${expense.getExpenseType}">Type:</td>
        </tr>

        <tbody id="transactions">
        <!-- transactions will be dynamically added here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>




</body>
</html>
```

Home Controller

```java
package com.example.demo.Web.Controllers;

import com.example.demo.Business.Entities.Expense;
import com.example.demo.Business.Entities.User;
import com.example.demo.Business.Services.ExpenseService;
import com.example.demo.Web.DTOs.EntryDTO;
import com.example.demo.Web.DTOs.SearchDTO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.swing.text.html.parser.Entity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


@Controller
public class HomeController {


    @Autowired
    ExpenseService expenseService;


    @Autowired
    HomeController(ExpenseService expenseService) {
        this.expenseService = expenseService;
    }

    //    Not yet implemented
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homePage(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "User") String name, Model model) {

        name = "Lennox";
        model.addAttribute("name", name);


        return "Home";
    }


    @GetMapping("/expense-list")
    public String expenseList(Model model) {

        List<Expense> displayResults = expenseService.getExpensesList();
        List<EntryDTO.ExpenseEntryDTO> resultsDTO = new ArrayList<>();


        System.out.println(displayResults);

        model.addAttribute("expenseListModel", displayResults);


        return "Home";
    }


    @PostMapping("/expense-list")
    public String getPerson(@ModelAttribute SearchDTO.ExpenseSearchDTO searchOBJ, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("expenseSearchModel", expenseService.searchBarFunc(searchOBJ));


        return "Home";


    }

    @PostMapping("/add-userEntry")
    public String addUserExpenseType (@ModelAttribute @RequestParam EntryDTO.ExpenseEntryDTO entryDTO, Model model) {



        List<Expense.TYPE> typeList = List.of(Expense.TYPE.Bill, Expense.TYPE.Education, Expense.TYPE.Travel, Expense.TYPE.Entertainment);



        System.out.println(entryDTO);

        return "Home";

    }
    

}
```

Expense Entity

```java
package com.example.demo.Business.Entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@ComponentScan(" com.example.demo.Business.EntitiesFields")
@Table(name="__Expense")
public non-sealed class Expense extends EntitiesFields {
   private TYPE type;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date date ;




// Default Constructor
   public Expense () {
       super();
       this.name = null;
       this.number = 0;
       this.date = null;
       this.id = null;
   }

   // Constructor with params

    public Expense (String name , Double cost , TYPE type) {

       this.name = name;
       this.number = cost;
       this.date = new Date();
       this.type = type;
       this.id = null;
    }



    // Getters and Setters
    public String getExpenseName () {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setExpenseName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Date getExpenseDate () {
        return this.date;
    }




    public Double getExpenseCost () {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setExpenseCost(Double cost) {
        this.number = cost;
    }

   public TYPE getExpenseType() {
       return this.type;
   }

   public void setExpenseType(Expense.TYPE type) {
       this.type = type;
   }


   public Long getExpenseId() { return this.id; }

    public Date getDate () {
       return this.date;
    }


    public enum TYPE {

        Bill {
            @Override
            public String toString(){return "Bill"; }
        }, Entertainment {
            @Override
            public String toString () {return "Entertainment";}
        }, Education{
            @Override
            public String toString() { return "Education" ;}
        }, Travel {
            @Override
            public String toString () { return  "Travel"; }
        }

    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "[Name: "+ this.getExpenseName() + " Cost: "+ this.getExpenseCost() + " Type: " + this.getExpenseType() + "]";
    }

}
```

Thanks everyone in advance for any input or guidance

I tried inputing the `th:field="entryDTO.cost"` instead of `*{cost}`, but I keep getting the same issue for both. Please see error messages below.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/Home.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1431) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1167) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1106) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "Home" - line 29, col 80)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "Home" - line 29, col 80)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:117) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'entryDTO' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:232) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 63 common frames omitted

2023-12-29T14:35:11.448Z ERROR 91508 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/Home.html]")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'entryDTO' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:232) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:79) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:241) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:327) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseStandaloneElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:96) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:706) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1431) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1167) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1106) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```